# Probability of drawing cards with both required and negative conditions

Tags: probability, combinations, problem-solving, card-games

Question: How do you check for a drawn card being any card other than a certain card when drawing cards WITHOUT replacement, but also apply conditions on the rest of the cards. To make things more complicated, the frequency of each card in the deck is different.

Context:

> Assume I have a deck of cards, with the frequency of each card being
> different.
>
> When drawing X cards where order does not matter and no replacement,
> what is the chance of getting:
>
> -At least 1 of each of (A, B, C) AND the remaining cards being any card  (including A, B, C) except card Z
>
> -At least 2 different cards of (A, B, C) AND the remaining cards being any card (including A, B, C) except card Z
>
> The problem is combining different conditions when there is no
> replacement. Does order here matter or no? How do I combine different
> conditions? I thought P(Z') - P(A'Z') - P(B'Z') - P(C'Z') but I am
> certain there is overlap between them, as A'Z' also includes some of
> B'Z'. Also, how is it possible to check for having at least two
> different cards?

Comment: If I can have a formula that would be good as I would like to test with different values.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: First, figure out the probability that you get a $Z$ card. Then, given that you didn't draw a $Z$ card (so there are only ($X -$ the number of $Z$ cards) to choose from), figure out the probabilities of your two events. The complete probabilities you are after are the products of these two conditional probabilities with the probability that you didn't get a $Z$ card. The conditional probability of the first is $1 - $ the probability of not getting any $A, B, C$ card. The second is a littile more complicated.

Comment: The second to last sentence of that comment was mistated. The probability of getting at least 1 each of $A, B, C$ is the product of the probabilities of getting at least one $A$, of getting at least one $B$, at least one $C$. The probability of getting at least one of some card is $1 - $ the probability of not getting that card at all.